# Log4j2 has multiple loggers not like log4j1

Tags: log4j2

I have recently upgraded from Log4j1 to Log4j2. We are using properties file in our project. I have defined only one logger in case of Log4j1 as below.

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, logfile

But in case of Log4j2 I have to define multiple loggers one for normal logger and another for root logger. Is it possible to define only one logger in Log4j2 like Log4j1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample configuration straight from the [Log4j web site](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This configuration only has the root Logger.  Why do you think more than one Logger definition is required?

For the record, here is a configuration using properties syntax from the same web page. It also only shows the root logger being configured.

```
status = error
dest = err
name = PropertiesConfig

property.filename = target/rolling/rollingtest.log

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %m%n
appender.console.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.console.filter.threshold.level = error

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = target/rolling2/test1-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=100MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5

logger.rolling.name = com.example.my.app
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```